# File Upload Control in Domino

Tags: file-upload, cordova, lotus-domino

I need to post a file to Domino Server from a PhoneGap Application.

Here is the PhoneGap File Transfer example
// !! Assumes variable fileURI contains a valid URI to a  text file on the device

```
var win = function(r) {
     console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
     console.log("Response = " + r.response);
     console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
      }

 var fail = function(error) {
  alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
 }  

 var options = new FileUploadOptions();
 options.fileKey="file";
 options.fileName=fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
 options.mimeType="text/plain";

 var params = new Object();
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

 options.params = params;

 var ft = new FileTransfer();
 ft.upload(fileURI, "http://some.server.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
 //This is a PHP example - Domino would be like
 // ft.upload(fileURI, "http://some.server.com/database.nsf/attachmentForm? createDocument", win, fail, options);
```

Does anyone know what needs to be done in Domino to get the file attachment that is being posted?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to create a form in Domino containing a File Upload control. You should be able to open the Domino form with a browser and see the generated html form that would normally be used. In there you will find all the info you need. This is of course dependent on the ft.upload method acting like an http multipart/form-data POST.