# Upload Captured Image to Domino Server via Phonegap FileTransfer.upload Method

Tags: cordova, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm using Phonegap to 1. capture a photo, 2. display the photo, 3. upload the photo. #1 and #2 are working.

For #3, I'm trying to use the FileTransfer.upload method to POST the captured photo to a Domino document (as an attachment in Rich Text?). The Phonegap API documentation explains ways to do this with PHP (sending request to a upload.php page), but I'm trying do accomplish this with an XPages/SSJS/Java solution. Was wondering if anyone has done something similar? Phonegap example is posted below. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="text/plain";

var params = new Object();
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURI, "http://some.server.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
```

Comment: I know Michael Butcher was able to get this to work. You may want to contact him. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796062/file-upload-control-in-domino

Comment: Thanks, Simon. I contacted Michael and he sent me some great resources.

Comment: I'm in the same situation and cant solve it. How did you solve this? Can you provide me some hints?

Comment: @DavidMarko, I did not solve this. Sorry. I am no longer developing with Phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

In your receiving XPage you should get the posted data as input stream like this:

```
facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getInputStream()
```

Then you can save it to a document like this:

[Temporary folder for attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233667/temporary-folder-for-attachments)